# shell script to replace space in 2nd column after delimiter in same file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

i have a file with below content in linux:

```
servername: tesing1001

os: Unix

bu:

aid: 132

location: anywhere

environment: dev-stg

application: ABCD testing space

city: kk
```

I want to replace content in same file with below data:

```
servername: tesing1001

 os: Unix

**bu: BLANK**  **>>>>here since value is empty i will set it as BLANK hardcoded**

aid: 132

location: anywhere

environment: dev-stg

**application: ABCD_testing_space**  **>>>>>here we will replace string space with "_"**

city: kk
```

all this thing we will do in same file . So, far i am trying to acheive above output with below logic

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cp -p /opsunix/dyfacter.txt /tmp/customized.txt.tmp
    awk -F ":" '{
                 if ($2 == "")
                  {
                    print $0  " blank"
                  } else {
                      print $0
                        } 
                }' /opsunix/dyfacter.txt > /tmp/customized.txt.tmp && mv /tmp/customized.txt.tmp /opsunix/dyfacter.txt
```

with the help of above code, am able to identify null value and replace it with **"blank"** string.

```
servername: tesing1001

 os: Unix

**bu: blank**  **>>>>done**

aid: 132

location: anywhere

environment: dev-stg

**application: ABCD testing space**  **>>>>>still need to correct**

city: kk
```

however 2nd last line i.e: **application: ABCD testing space**
am not able to convert it as **application: ABCD_testing_space**.

appliying `sed -i 's/ /_/g' /opsunix/dyfacter.txt`  is replacing all spaces in file after : .

purpose is to replace space in string .

Please help!

Comment: The predictable temporary file name is a security problem. Better to use the system-supplied `mktemp` if you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, this will change all null values to `BLANK` and strings with consecutive spaces between the values to change the space to `_` after the delimiter `:`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/^([^ ]*: +)([^ ]*) +/\1\2_/;ta;s/: +?$/: BLANK/' input_file
servername: tesing1001

os: Unix

bu: BLANK

aid: 132

location: anywhere

environment: dev-stg

application: ABCD_testing_space

city: kk
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.
I replace all spaces with an _
After that i replace all ":_" with ":  "

```
foo=${str// /_}
echo $foo
echo ${foo/:_/: }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk  (gawk in particular):

```
awk -F ': ' '/^application/ { gsub(" ","_",$2) } /^bu/ { gsub("","BLANK",$2)}1' file

Set the field delimiter to ": " and then where the line starts with "application", use awks, gsub function to replace all instances of " " with "_" in the second field. With lines starting with bu, replace "" with "BLANK" in the second field
```

This will output the amendments to the screen, to write the data back to the file, use a temporary file and so:

```
awk -F ': ' '/^application/ { gsub(" ","_",$2) } /^bu/ { gsub("","BLANK",$2)}1' file > file.tmp && cp -f file.tmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **awk** you could set the FS *(Field Separator)* to a colon followed by optional spaces, and the OFS *(Ouput Field Separator)* to `:`

Using a pattern, you could match if the line starts with non whitespace chars followed by `:` and then optional spaces only.

If that is the case, print out the first field with the OFS and "BLANK" and move to the *next* line as there is nothing to substitute on this line.

For all the other lines, replace `" "` with `_`

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=":[[:space:]]*";
  OFS=": "
}
/^[^[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*$/{
  print $1 OFS "BLANK"
  next
}
{
  gsub(" ","_", $2)
}1
' file
```

Output

```
servername: tesing1001

os: Unix

bu: BLANK

aid: 132

location: anywhere

environment: dev-stg

application: ABCD_testing_space

city: kk
```

---

With **gnu awk** you might also match the whole line using a pattern and 2 capture groups, and do the replacement based on the value of capture group 2.

```
awk '
match($0, /^([^[:blank:]]+:[[:blank:]]*)(.+)?$/, a) {
  if (a[2] != "") {
    print a[1] gensub(" ", "_", "g", a[2])
    next
  }
  print a[1] "BLANK"
}
' file
```